# RegExp: Match only single substring occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Hello I need to replace only single occurrence of substring
Example:

> Some sentence **#x;#x;#x**; with **#x;#x;** some **#x;** words **#x;** need in replacing.

Need replace only single **#x;** by **#y;** and get following string

> Some sentence **#x;#x;#x;** with **#x;#x;** some **#y;** words **#y;** need in replacing.

Some note: My string will contain unicode chars and operator \b doesn't work.

Comment: Please show the code you are trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match #x; repeated any number of times, and only replace those where it occurs once:

```
sentence = sentence.replace(/((?:#x;)+)/g, function(m) {
  return m.length == 3 ? '#y;' : m;
});
```

Comment: +1: I think this is better than the lookbehind workaround. It's certainly much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest regular expression to match single occurences of `#x;` only would be to use a lookbehind and a lookahead assertion.

```
/(?<!#x;)#x;(?!#x;)/
```

However Javascript does not support lookbehinds so you can try this workaround using only lookaheads instead:

```
/(^[\S\s]{0,2}|(?!#x;)[\S\s]{3})#x;(?!#x;)/
```

Complete example:

```
> s = 'Some sentence #x;#x;#x; with #x;#x; some #x; words #x; need in replacing.'
> s = s.replace(/(^[\S\s]{0,2}|(?!#x;)[\S\s]{3})#x;(?!#x;)/g, '$1#y;')
"Some sentence #x;#x;#x; with #x;#x; some #y; words #y; need in replacing."
```

Answer (score 1):

A single `#x;` could qualify by having white-space before and after.
In this case you could use this:

```
str.replace( /(\s+)#x;(\s+)/g, '$1#y;$2' )
```

Answer (score 0):

use `str.replace('/(#x;)+/g','#y;')`

Comment: I think that you mean `/(#x;){1}/g` rather than `'/#x;{1}/'`, but the `{1}` still doesn't keep it from replacing each occurance on it's own.

Comment: You still have apostrophes around it, so it's not a regular expression but a string. It will look for the text `/(#x;)+/g` in the string, not `#x;`. The change from `{1}` to `+` means that it will replace `#x;#x;#x;` with `#y;` instead of `#y;#y;#y;`, but it will still not only replace the single occurances.